# About scala Double datatype precision

Tags: scala, validation, type-conversion

I'm fairly a newbie to scala and in my baby steps, i'm  using Centso 7.2 and Scala 2.12 with sbt console: here is my question is:

```
scala> val Y=5.12345938988398773983748934789473289472384723984723849
Y: Double = 5.123459389883988
```

This is with 15 precision and giving the value as excpected

and

```
scala> val u=4.91839028309283892389012
u: Double = 4.9183902830928385
```

This is supposed to be 4.9183902830928 ***390*** ---> may be I'm missing something if not then it is loosing the precision value.

Can you please help me understand how Scala is treating this causing this precision inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, computers store numbers not in decimal but in binary format. And when it comes to floating point numbers they use [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

[Here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/43) you can find a great explanation and examples of how computer converts floating point numbers to and from IEEE 754 format.